# Laravel: get additional ressources for injected object

Tags: laravel

I have a ressource controller with a function like this:

```
public function show(Table0 $myData) {
   return $myData->with('additionalTable1')->with('addtionalTable2')->first();
}
```

but that will always return the first object from the database. Always the same one no matter what Id I submit.

This variant works:

```
public function show(int $myData) {
   return Table0::where('key', $myData)->with('additionalTable1')->with('addtionalTable2')->first();
}
```

But it doesn't make use of the injection. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [`Route Model Binding`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding) the value of `$myData` will be the object you're looking for so `->first()` is not required.

```
public function show(Table0 $myData) {
   return $myData->with(['additionalTable1', 'addtionalTable2'])->get();
}
```

Comment: $myData will be the object but the above code returns a TypeError (while just returning $myData does not).

Comment: @NDDT It will be a response type error doe to using `with`. Adding `->get()` to the end of the return statement should solve it.

Comment: then I am getting a list of all customers, instead of just the one.

Comment: Is `$myData` definitely a single object instance and not something else?

Comment: yes $myDate is the desired object, but after running ->get() I get the entire table with all objects. And if I used first() instead I get the first element of the table. Not the one that was injected.

Comment: If you’re certain the $myData is correct then I suspect something with your relationships is causing the issue. This is literally the syntax used in the Laravel documentation.